# How can I replace a Custom ArrayAdapter with Fragment i.e. getFragmentmanager() gives error message

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a little and bit complicated problem i.e. I am implementing a listview in android. One list item has almost 6 children in it. The problem is the list itemClickListener is not performing well because of textviews in it. I mean on textview it does not perform itemClickListing. So I think I have to implement the clickListeners for every TextView individually. **Now the problem starts:** ListView's itemClickListener (it is inside the Fragment class):

```
        JournalAdapter adapter = new JournalAdapter(JournalListFragment.activity, R.layout.journal_list_items, journals);

        ListView listView1 = (ListView)JournalListFragment.activity.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Utilities.selectedJnrlId = view.getId() ;

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new JournalAddUpdateFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }

        });
```

I used custom adapter here. When I implement the itemClickListener on listView; I am in a class that extends from Fragment class. So I just replace the fragment in result of listView-itemClickListener But when I goes to the other class i.e. **CustomArrayAdapter** I can't do this because of **getFragmentManager()** . It gives an error because my Custom-ArrayAdapter class does extends from Fragment class. So is there any reasonable solution for it?
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood the code is not finding because it's in a subclass of your fragment.

it's just a simple matter of pointing the compiler to the correct class.

you'll call it like this:

```
MyFragment.this.getFragmentManager.beginTran...  etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually using

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

in textviews. This caused the problem for me. It made the textviews unclickable. Reason, I dont know. So I replaced it with

```
android:text=""
```

and also used

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
android:focusable="false"
```

in TextViews.
In RelativeLayout containing these TextViews; I used

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
```

Finally my listview became clickable with only an **itemClickListener**. No clickListeners required for the TextViews individually.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using ListView's click listener you can manually bind listener to your view in `getView()`. The only trick there is you need to know what view triggered the click, but solution is pretty simple - use `setTag()` and as tag put i.e. listview's position of the row. Then `getTag()` in on click listener, get your view's corresponding row and proceed

Comment: use this             View view = getView() ;
            view.setClickable(true) ;
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Utilities.selectedJnrlId = getView().getId() ;
     
     FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new JournalAddUpdateFragment());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
     transaction.commit();
     
    }
             
            }); but now the click-listener is not working "commented the 1st clicklistener"